# What OS versions are supported by Watson Studio Local?

Tags: data-science-experience, watson-studio, dsx-local

I have Windows 10 installed and planning for Watson Studio Local installation. Is this OS supported or not ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://datascience.ibm.com/docs/content/desktop/install.html) of DSX Desktop, you should be be install it on Mac/Windows/Linux. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Find here the documentation for DSX Local: https://datascience.ibm.com/docs/content/local/requirements.html

"This configuration requires a minimum of three servers (either physical or virtual machines) with a RHEL7.2+ operating system."

DSX Desktop is available for Windows, macOS and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its supported. You can use the desktop client on Microsoft Windows 7, Windows 8, or Windows 10, and also on macOS Sierra and Ubuntu, Debian, Red Hat Enterprise Linux, CentOS, Fedora, as pointed out at the following link:

https://datascience.ibm.com/docs/content/desktop/requirements.html?audience=desktop

As mentioned on previous answers you can find the server requirements on the following page:

https://datascience.ibm.com/docs/content/local/requirements.html?audience=local